# Proving that if $c$ is a local maximum, then $f^{\prime\prime}(c) \leq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$. Suppose $f, f^\prime, f^{\prime \prime}$ exist on $(a,b)$. Prove that if $f$ has a local maximum at $c \in (a,b)$, then $f^{\prime\prime}(c) \leq 0$.

I can see why this is true because if $f^{\prime\prime}(c) \geq 0$, the function $f$ would be concave up and a point to the right of $c$ would be a local maximum, but I'm struggling to write a rigorous proof.

I know that since $c$ is a local max of $f$, we know that $f^{\prime}(c) = 0$. Then 
$f^{\prime}{(c)} = \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} = 0$. I also know that $f^{\prime\prime}(c) = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f^{\prime}(x) - f^{\prime}(c)}{x - c}  = \lim_{x\ \to c}\frac{f^\prime(x)}{x - c}$ but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Note that a function that is concave up at $x=c$ isn't necessarily larger to the *right* of $c$: consider $f(x) = 1/x$ for some $c>0$.

Comment: Consider the sup of all zeros of $f'$ which are $<c$. If this number is $c$, than show that $f$ is constant on a left neighborhood of $c$. Else $f'$ is increasing (not necessarily in a strict way) on the left of $c$, starting with the sup. With the same argument decreasing on the other side. So $f''$ is $\ge 0$, respectively $\le 0$ left, resp. right from $c$. Being continuous...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $f"$ is continous. Suppose $f"(c)> 0$. Since $f'(c) =0$, There exists an interval $I$ such that $f'(x) >f'(c) =0$ for $x$ in $I, x>c$.This implies that $f$ strictly increases on $[c, x]. $ Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

We can show this using Taylor`s expansion aswell. We can take the first order taylor expansion around $x_0$ with Lagrange's remainder :
$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac {f''(c_x)(x-x_0)^2} 2$$ for some $c_x\in(x_0,x)$ or $(x,x_0) $ and $x_0\in(a,b)$.

Since $c$ is a local maximum, we have $f'(c)=0$:

$$f(x)=f(c)+\frac {f''(c_x)(x-x_0)^2} 2$$
Since $\frac {(x-x_0)^2} 2\geq 0$, The sign of $f''(c_x)$ determines if we have a maximum or a minimum.